# How to use shell parallel with two files

Tags: shell, gnu-parallel

I want to use parallel in this example:

```
cat codigos.txt | parallel -j 10 "wget http://mywebsite.com/teste?id={}&x=&date=01/01/2017" --load-cookies=cookies.txt
```

I have three files: `codigos.txt`, a file with the ids, `dates.txt`, a file with the dates and `cookies.txt` the file with the cookie that I need to do the request.

What I want to do is to save the response from mywebsite.com for each url, using the contents of my files.

Problems:

1. How do I do to use information coming from two files?
2. The url is cut at the '&' (even when I put the quotes). Example:

`request made to http://mywebsite.com/teste?id=1`

As this example (but without put the space or cut because of the '&'):

```
cat abc-file | parallel -a - -a def-file echo
```

reference: https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_tutorial.html

Comment: I forgot to say, but the request just goes until the &, how do I say that the & is a character and not a command?

Comment: The main thrust of your question is very unclear, but as to the other, enclose the URL in `'strong quotes'`, which prevents the `&`s from being parsed by the shell.

Comment: I have two files:
- codigos.txt: its a file with the ids;
- dates.txt: its a file with the dates;

What I want to do is:
-Save the response from mywebsite.com for each url.

Comment: And the 'strong quotes' are not working, I tried with another website without using the parallel (ex: wget http://mywebsite.com/teste?fcodigo=1231213'&'fvinculo='&'month=01/01/2017. But it doesn't work when I get the code from a file.

Comment: `mywget() { wget "http://mywebsite.com/teste?id=$1&x=&date=$2" --load-cookies=cookies.txt; }; export -f mywget; parallel mywget :::: codigos.txt dates.txt`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to run:

```
wget http://mywebsite.com/teste?id=codigo1&x=&date=01/01/2017" --load-cookies=cookies.txt
wget http://mywebsite.com/teste?id=codigo1&x=&date=02/01/2017" --load-cookies=cookies.txt
wget http://mywebsite.com/teste?id=codigo1&x=&date=03/01/2017" --load-cookies=cookies.txt
wget http://mywebsite.com/teste?id=codigo2&x=&date=01/01/2017" --load-cookies=cookies.txt
wget http://mywebsite.com/teste?id=codigo2&x=&date=02/01/2017" --load-cookies=cookies.txt
wget http://mywebsite.com/teste?id=codigo2&x=&date=03/01/2017" --load-cookies=cookies.txt
```

if the file `codigos.txt` contains:

```
codigo1
codigo2
```

and `dates.txt` contains:

```
01/01/2017
02/01/2017
03/01/2017
```

then this will work:

```
mywget() {
    wget "http://mywebsite.com/teste?id=$1&x=&date=$2" --load-cookies=cookies.txt;
}
export -f mywget
parallel mywget :::: codigos.txt dates.txt
```